# Check from string month of date?

Tags: php, datetime, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

How to achieve from string `2015-12-08 10:01:01` check if that date is in current month using Laravel features?

I get that string from database and should check it if it belongs to current month, if so then i need to update that row, if not then create new row (each month has it's own row in table).

So far i have tried

```
$date = date('2015-12-08 10:01:01');
dd(date_format("m",$date));

and 

$date = date('m','2015-12-08 10:01:01');
dd($date);
```

But don't work

Any help would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(date('mY',strtotime('2015-12-08 10:01:01')) == date('mY')) 
  //current month
```

Note that i am using Year also, you can't only compare a month to find out whether its the current month. Year and Month both have to be looked at.

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/482027)**

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks a lot :)